# How to update the content of a userconrol if is outside the update panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control which is inside a update panel.This user control has a event like

```
protected void ucNote_NoteAdded(object sender, NoteAddedEventArgs noteAddedArgs)
    {}
```

Inside this i am checking a checkbox which is outside the update panel.
But it is not checking the checkbox ?
In firebug i found that the html for that checkbox is not rendered.
What is the way to do that?

Comment: checkbox is inside a different usercontrol
and it is inside a update panel

Comment: Either place the checkbox inside an updatepanel or write some simple javascript to update the checkbox value.

Comment: actually the checkbox is in a different user control.And that usercontrol is inside a update panel.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add trigger for UpdatePanel which contain checkbox?

```
           <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnlMy">
                <ContentTemplate>
                     <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSomeCheckbox"
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ucNote" EventName="NoteAdded" />                    
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: No i have not added any trigger in the update pannel which contains checkbox.But i found the another way to do that. update the second update panel on event.
Thanks for the answer.